# Disable sanitize_file_name on upload without modifying functions.php

Tags: filters, actions, multi-language

I am looking for a way to disable `sanitize_file_name` function without modifying the `functions.php` or `formatting.php`. I am uploading files that have other language file names and all I am getting are dashes right now.

I found out how to remedy this, but it is by commenting a line out in the `functions.php` and I do not want to do that. Here is the line that I am talking about: (starting on line 1856 of functions.php)

```
function wp_unique_filename( $dir, $filename, $unique_filename_callback = null ) {
    // Sanitize the file name before we begin processing.
    $filename = sanitize_file_name($filename); <--- If I comment this out, it works like I want.
```

I am sure that I can apply a filter of some sorts, but I have never used filters and would be interested in learning. I looked at the Codex, but it did not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding the following code to the functions.php file in your theme directory and see if works for you

```
function keep_raw_filename( $filename, $filename_raw )
{
    return $filename_raw;
}

add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'keep_raw_filename', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: That will do the trick, but be aware that this may not necessarily be safe. If people can upload files to your site with arbitrary filenames, then there is a chance of bad-things-happening.

Comment: @czerspalace Unfortunately, that did not work. It is still adding the dashes to the file name instead of the language characters that I need.

Comment: @czerspalace Do you have another recommendation? For some reason, the above answer is not working. Could it be the priority?